# How to adjust the font of the entry numbers in TOC?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, xetex, fontsize

[image: ugly font size]

My first LaTeX article looks ugly, see above.

How to adjust the entry numbers to look more large and in bold? And, without changing the following title text?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}

\title{Hello, LaTeX}
\author{hello@latex.com}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Hello, Section!}
Section 1

\subsection{Hello, SubSection!}
SubSection 1

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Or at least tell us which document class you're using.

Comment: @karlkoeller, I attached a MWE in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load the `tocloft` package and add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\large\bfseries}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\large\bfseries}

\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}

\title{Hello, LaTeX}
\author{hello@latex.com}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Hello, Section!}
Section 1

\subsection{Hello, SubSection!}
SubSection 1

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also have `\subsubsection`s add also

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpresnum}{\large\bfseries}
```